# Windows 10 VM suddenly BSODs

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Hyper-V VM running on a Windows 10 host.

- Until yesterday, everything worked fine.
- Since yesterday, the guest VM bluescreens with an error code 0xc000021a immediately after starting.
- Resetting the VM to an earlier snapshot (taken months ago) won't fix the issue - the same BSOD occurs.

Thus, I can only think of two possible reasons:

- Some new problem on the host (unlikely, since all other VMs work fine) or
- some undetected bit flip in the base vhdx file (which, according to the NTFS modified date, has not been touched for months).

Are there any other possible explanations that I am missing?

Comment: How would the NTFS modified date be relevant on a HD disc flip? How would that go throug hthe hardware checksum and not result in a write error ("fat chance").

Comment: @TomTom: It wouldn't. The part in parenthesis is an explanation for the "undetected".

Comment: Did you restart the host and start them in another order? (which would sort of move them around in memory - I am very inclined to say ram). Is this server grade hardware? (read: ECC RAM)

Comment: @TomTom: Good idea! Just tried that, didn't make a difference, unfortunately. No, it's consumer hardware.

Comment: For what it's worth, that bugcheck code [means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560177(v=vs.85).aspx) that a system-critical process (e.g. CSRSS) died.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a6614a2-05e6-45ac-b363-43814c205625/blue-screen-on-boot-in-a-vm-0xc000021a?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv suggests you need a cumulative update installed.

Comment: @EricLaw: Thanks, that's good to know and I hope it helps future readers of this question. Since almost two years have passed since I asked the question, I have reinstalled the VM in the meantime.